# How to check the occurence of the SelectedIndexChange event of a dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

How can we check whether the selectedIndexChange event of a dropdownlist is fired or not? Can we use a boolean varible or is there any predefined method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

```
<asp:Dropdownlist runat="server" id="ddl1" OnSelectedIndexChange="ddl1_OnSelectedIndexChange" AutoPostback="true">
<asp:ListItem text="1" value="1"/>
</asp:Dropdownlist>
<Asp:Label id="label1" runat="server"/>
```

C#

```
protected void ddl1_OnSelectedIndexChange(object sender, Eventargs e)
{
  label1.Text = "yay! selected index change event fired"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would subscribe an event to the SelectedIndexChanged event on your drop down list and handle it yourself.  Depending on when in the page lifecycle you need it constrains your options for how to handle storing a boolean of if the ddl has changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On the client there is a 'onchange' event you can handle.

On the server side subscribe to the 'SelectedIndexChanged' event. For this to fire for the dropdown control AutoPostback property must be set to true